# Proving or disproving the existence of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose the vector space $V$ is spanned by $(1,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1), (1,1,0,0)$. Is it possible to find a subspace U of $\mathbb R^4$ such that $V \subsetneq U \subsetneq \mathbb R^4$? Note that "$\subsetneq$" here stands for "is a proper subset of".

I have checked that $(1,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1), (1,1,0,0)$ are linearly independent and as such form a basis for $V$. Hence $dim(V) = 3$. Clearly $dim(\mathbb R^4) = 4$. Thus $V \subsetneq \mathbb R^4$. How should I proceed to prove or disprove that such a vector space $U$ exists?

Comment: if such a $U$ exists, what will be the dimension of $U$?

Comment: $3$? Because if $dim(U) = 4$, then $U = \mathbb R^4$ right?

Comment: no. if such a $U$ exists then it's dimension will be at least 4, because it properly contains a 3-dimensional subspace. and this will force that $U = \mathbb{R}^4.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If $V\subsetneqq U$, there must be some vector $u\in U\setminus V$. Show that

$$\{u,\langle 1,0,1,0\rangle,\langle 0,1,0,1\rangle,\langle 1,1,0,0\rangle\}$$

must be linearly independent and hence that $\dim U\ge 4$. Then use the same argument to show that if $U\subsetneqq\Bbb R^4$, $\Bbb R^4$ must have dimension at least $5$.

Comment: Assume such a vector space $U$ exists. Then $\exists u \in U \setminus V$. Hence $u$ is not a linear combination of $(1,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1), (1,1,0,0)$ and so {$u, (1,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1), (1,1,0,0)$} can $possibly$ be a basis for $U$. So $dim(U) \ge 4$. Since $U \subsetneq \mathbb R^4$, by the same argument $\exists v \in \mathbb R^4$ that is linearly independent to $u, (1,0,1,0), (0,1,0,1), (1,1,0,0)$ which means that $\mathbb R^4 \ge 5$, which is a contradiction. Hence such a vector space $U$ cannot exist. Is this correct?

Comment: @Vizuna: You’ve got it.

Comment: @Vizuna: You’re welcome, and thank *you*.